Dynamodb put_item silent fail
Is this a phenomenon whereby using lambda's to concurrently write to a dynamodb table using put_item requests the writes fail without raising any exception.
I have a dynamodb table setup to use on-demand read and write.
Up to 100 lamdbdas are writing to the table at a time.
I've included the outputs from cloudwatch  at the time this is happening.
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import time

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('myTable')

def lambda_handler(event, context, items, retries=5):
    for item in items:
        for i in range(retries):
            try:
                table.put_item(Item=item)
                # Apply a check to verify that the item is loaded
                response = table.get_item(Key={'PrimaryKey': item['PrimaryKey']})
                loaded_item = response.get('Item')
                if loaded_item == item:
                    break
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Item verification failed")
            except ClientError as e:
                if e.response['Error']['Code'] in ['ProvisionedThroughputExceededException', 'ThrottlingException']:
                    time.sleep(2 ** i)  # Exponential backoff
                else:
                    raise
        else:
            print(f"Failed to write item after retries: {item}")

# Example usage
items = [
    {'PrimaryKey': 'value1', 'Attribute': 'value1'},
    {'PrimaryKey': 'value2', 'Attribute': 'value2'},
    # Add more items as needed
]
lambda_handler(None, None, items)



How are you confirming failures?

I have done tests to see that all items are loaded, this is where I noticed missing items. I know its not shown in the code above but after a put_item I immediately read back from the table the item to confirm it has been written. I found that about 50 of 40000 items are missing.

Can you share the read code

I have given a bit more detail. If I run this code and have several lambdas writing concurrently to the dynamodb table I start getting verification exceptions raised because the put_item writes have failed silently.

Added an answer that should clear things up for you.

You're getting this issue because your reads are eventually consistent.
Do this:
table.get_item(Key={'PrimaryKey': item['PrimaryKey'],
ConsistentRead=True}

The difference here is that you are guaranteed the latest version of the data.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html

Thanks for your answer, I included this in my code. The amount of failed writes that I was measuring dropped significantly, however there are still failed writes happening. I still have to verify that the write took place as I am not getting an exception when it fails

What's the exception for it failing?

There is no exception, the only way I know it failed to write is by verifying that the item is in the table. It happens roughly 20 items fail from 1 million writes.

Your Lambda is hitting the maximum timeout which is leading it to have timeout failures.

Do you mean the 900 second maximum? The lambdas are finishing long before it reaches 900 seconds. Or are you talking about some other time limit?

They're not. You're seeing failures and your duration is clearly hitting 900s, which is what causes the failures

No the lambdas are finishing after around 9 minutes. I think the issue is Async Events being dropped. When this happens If all retries fail and no Dead-Letter Queue (DLQ) or Event Destination is configured, the event will be dropped without further retries or alerts

Your Lambda has failures, and your duration is showing 900ms.
